# Powershell and REGEX to pull Information out of a LDAP Query

Tags: regex, powershell

Sorry for this question I am still a REGEX newbie.

I am using powershell to create a script, and I need to create a series of IF THEN statements

I have an array that contains the following LDAP Queries:

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=XXXX, XX)(sAMAccountName=%LogonUser%))

(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=XXXX, XX)(sAMAccountName=%LogonUser%))

(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=*XXXXXX*)(sAMAccountName=%LogonUser%))

(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(scriptpath=XXXXX*.XXX)(sAMAccountName=%LogonUser%))
```

Using a For Loop and REGEX, I want to be able to pull all mentions of "PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName" and "scriptpath" between the ( and =

Also further down in the script I would like to be able to pull all the Xs between the = and )

Is there a way to do both? They don't have to be in the same statement. Two separate statements are fine

The Xs represent City, State, and in case of the scriptpath query a File name. However as you can see the city and state is not always the same patten.

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: show us expected output

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow, people are happy to help with scripting errors or problems but please note this is not a code writing service. Share what you have tried along with any error messages. Including expected output is also helpful.

Comment: I can code the Powershell script myself, I am just not that good with REGEX. I would just like a regex to pull out "PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName","PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName","PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName","scriptpath".

Comment: `Select-String -Pattern '\((?<Param>PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName|ScriptPath)=(?<Data>.*?)\)' -Path .\ldap.txt | % Matches | % { $_.Groups['Param'].Value; $_.Groups['Data'].Value }` - I don't get why you want to use a for loop, or why you want the repeats of of the LDAP property names if they're going to be separate from the data, or why you chose regexes if you can't regex - split the string by `(` and `)` with `$line.Split('()')` ...

Comment: I am mapping drives based on the Group Policy Preferences XML File. The client has different drive requirements based on the office location AND if they have a batch file name in the user's AD script path. I need to loop though the LDAP queries in the XML file and compare them to the user's Office location and check to see of the script path is NULL. That is why I need to loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Should Work.

Regex:

```
(scriptpath|PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName)=(.+?)(?=\))
```

Input:

```
(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=XXXX, XX)(sAMAccountName=%LogonUser%))

(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=XXXX, XX)(sAMAccountName=%LogonUser%))

(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=*XXXXXX*)(sAMAccountName=%LogonUser%))

(&(objectCategory=user)(objectClass=user)(scriptpath=XXXXX*.XXX)(sAMAccountName=%LogonUser%))
```

Output:

```
PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=XXXX, XX
PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=XXXX, XX
PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=*XXXXXX*
scriptpath=XXXXX*.XXX
```

Groups: (For first match)

```
$0 = PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName=XXXX, XX => Full Match
$1 = PhysicalDeliveryOfficeName
$2 = XXXX, XX
```

See: https://regex101.com/r/thHmlq/3

Comment: Thanks for your help. This worked like a charm!